# How to come up with a junit testcase for this?

Tags: java, junit, netbeans-8

This is the code that i create a junit testing for and the automated junit in netbeans generated test cases but i don't now how to do the testing if you guys can please show me a example.

```
class Account
{
    private double balance=100;
    private String accountNumber;
    private boolean firstTime=true;

public void deposit(double howMuch)
    {
         if(howMuch>0)
        {
            balance=balance+howMuch;
            System.out.println(howMuch+ "was successfully deposited into your account" + "The new balance of your account "+balance);
        }
        else
        {
           System.err.println("Please do not enter negative values");
        }
    }
}
```

This the junit testing class so please tell me how to change the null value and run the testCase .

```
package BankSys;

import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.AfterClass;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.BeforeClass;
import org.junit.Test;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;

/**
 *
 * @author SweAtBAr
 */
public class AccountTest {

    public AccountTest() {
    }

    @BeforeClass
    public static void setUpClass() {
    }

    @AfterClass
    public static void tearDownClass() {
    }

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() {
    }

    /**
     * Test of deposit method, of class Account.
     */
    @Test(expected=NullPointerException.class)
    public void testDeposit() {
        System.out.println("deposit");
        double howMuch = 0.0;
        Account instance = null;
        instance.deposit(howMuch);
        // TODO review the generated test code and remove the default call to fail.
        fail("The test case is a prototype.");
       }
```

Comment: You cant test for null deposit parameter as you accept parameter as double and its primitive and not Double type. null is valid for object reference only.

Comment: call your `deposit` method with a positive value then test if your `balance` value is rigthly set. Then do it with a negative value and test if the `balance`value is still the same.

Comment: I don't get why you expect a NullPointerException to test your deposit method

Answer (score 0):

In method testDeposit() you should instantiate 'instance' of type Account.

```
Account instance = new Account();
```

You may add an additional constructor that initializes account number and balance (Account class attributes):

```
public class Account
{
  private double balance;
  private String accountNumber;
  private boolean firstTime;

  public void deposit(double howMuch)
  {
     if(howMuch>0)
     {
        balance=balance+howMuch;
        System.out.println(howMuch+ "was successfully deposited into your account" + "The new balance of your account "+balance);
    }
    else
    {
       System.err.println("Please do not enter negative values");
    }
  }

  public Account(final String accountNumber, final double balance) {
    this.accountNumber = accountNumber;
    this.balance = balance;
    this.firstTime = true;
  }

  public Account() {}

  public double getBalance() {
    return balance;
  } 

  public void setBalance(final double balance) {
    this.balance = balance;
  }

  // Add here setters/getters for accountNumber and firstTime
}
```

Next in your test method you have to check that the balance value is correct after having done a deposit:

```
instance.deposit(howMuch);
assertEquals(expectedValue, instance.getBalance());
```

Comment: In which way is that supposed to answer the question?

Comment: @Oliver what should i put for arguments for account constructor?

Comment: Usually ones adds a constructor that initialize the attributes. See my edit in the answer.

Comment: @Oliver it did not work constructor does not get values

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `(expected=NullPointerException.class)`, if you don't expect deposit method will throw NullPointerException.

Simple test case would be:

```
@Test
public void testDeposit() {
    System.out.println("deposit");
    double howMuch = 1.0;
    Account instance = new Account(); 
    instance.deposit(howMuch);

    // As mentioned by Olivier Meurice, you may have a method to get the balance
    // To test whether the account balance is correct
    assertEquals(1.0, instance.getBalance());
   }
```

Comment: what should i put for arguments for account constructor?

Comment: It depends on your use case. As suggested by Olivier, you may add accountNumber and balance as arguments.
Then you can instantiate Account object by
`Account instance = new Account("12345678", 100.0);`